# Script is slow, returns console error, but works

Tags: javascript, json, performance, console, jsonp

I'm making a function to output an external JSONP script *(returning Norwegian postal cities)*. I have got it to work, however, it's very slow. In the network tab in developer tools, it sometimes takes 2 seconds to load the script and return the result in the `<output>` (and I suspect it's taking even more time when I'm not watching).

[image: Network loading]

What I've also seen is that my function returns a console error on the JSONP output code, and I don't know why - in my experience, console errors makes everything stop working, but even though it's slow, it returns the postal city as expected.

[image: Console errors]

It says something like `Unable to get the property postal_codes when it is undefined or has a null reference`. Is this the thing is causing the slowness? I have copied my code to JSLint for detecting errors in the code, but nothing regarding this.

---

This is my (what I think of as simple) code:

```
var output = document.querySelector("output"),
    input = document.querySelector("input");
function nr(data) {
    output.textContent = data.postal_codes[0].city; // returns console error on postal_codes but works
}
function postalcode() {
    if(input.value.length == 4) {
        if(document.getElementById("json")) { // if the script already exists, remove before re-appending
            document.getElementById("json").parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById("json"));
        }
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "http://adressesok.posten.no/api/v1/postal_codes.json?postal_code=" + input.value + "&callback=nr";
        script.defer = true;
        script.id = "json";
        script.onerror = function() { // when the script src returns 404
            output.textContent = "Invalid number";
        };
        // the below should only load when script src doesn't return 404 (onerror), onload doesn't work
        document.head.appendChild(script);
        nr();
    }
    else if(!input.value.length) {
        output.textContent = "";
    }
    else {
        output.textContent = "Has to be 4 digits";
    }
}
input.addEventListener("keyup", postalcode);
input.addEventListener("paste", postalcode);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcp837st/3/) - try inserting numbers like 2000, 1112 and 1448, which should work, and numbers like 1111 and 9999, which isn't real postal codes and returns a 404 error.

Comment: If you call the function `nr(data)` with `nr()`, the `data` will be undefined and `data.postal_codes` will produce an error. Also, what callback is your JSONP calling?

Comment: @Amadan Thanks - but then, what should I put in the function call? I've tried data, but that returns another console error.

Comment: I see your JSONP is `nr(...)`. You shouldn't be calling `nr` at all, JSONP does. The calls JSONP performs account for the fact that your program works; the calls to `nr()` you do yourself generate errors. Just delete that line. About slowness, that's their server: nothing you can do.

Comment: @Amadan I see, if I remove the function call, it still works, and doesn't produce a console error. Thanks - however, it's still really slow, don't you think? Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: Already answered: their server. The AJAX call from my location returns in 400ms in case of a 404, and 750ms for a valid query. It's not your code, it's theirs.

Comment: Hmm, my tests show 1-2s for a valid, and .7s-1.5s for a 404. But that may be my browser? Also, one more thing, what if I don't want the script to be appended when `onerror`? I've tried `script.onload = function() { ... }` before the `onerror`, but this makes only the `onerror` work, and `onload` never calls, at least not in IE11. Do you know anything?

Comment: @Amadan fiddle for `onload`/`onerror`: http://jsfiddle.net/hcp837st/4/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67592/discussion-between-amadan-and-mangseth).